# Homomorphism $\phi: \Bbb Z\to R$ where $R$ is a ring with identity.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I want to find all ring homomorphisms from $\phi:\Bbb Z\to R$ where $(R,+,\cdot)$ is an arbitrary ring with identity. Where $\phi: 1\mapsto 1_R$.

I think since $\phi(1)=1_R\implies \phi(1+1)=\phi(1)+\phi(1)=1_R+1_R$

We must have that the homomorphism is the identity map, and since this was by construction under those conditions, I have a feeling all such maps are the identity map, and it is therefore unique. Is this intuition correct?

---

$\phi(n\times 1) = \phi(1)+\phi(1)+\cdots+\phi(1)=1_R+1_R+\cdots+1_R$

Comment: They cannot be the "identity" map since in general $R\neq \Bbb Z$, but they will always send $1_\Bbb Z\mapsto 1_R$, and this determines the map uniquely as sending $n\in\Bbb Z\mapsto n\cdot 1_R$. Thus there is always a unique map $\Bbb Z\to R$ for any ring with $1$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff True, silly of me, thanks

Comment: Depending on your definition of ring homomorphism, it might be non-unique. For instance, if we have $R = \Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$, then $\phi_1(1) = (1, 0)$, $\phi_2(1) = (0,1)$ and $\phi(3) = (1, 1)$ all respect multiplication and addition. However, some (most?) text also demand $\phi(1_{\Bbb Z}) = 1_R$, and in that case the homomorphism is unique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right it is unique, basically for the reasons you gave. 
However, it is not "the identity map" as the term is usually understood. For example note that when $R$ is finite, such as $R = \mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$, your map certainly cannot even be injective.

What is true, and maybe you meant this, is that for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ you *necessarily* have $\phi(n)= n \cdot 1_R$.

To complete you argument you should consider negative integers too, and depending on how formal you want to be give a proof for the general case for positive $n$ via induction.